# Run SpeechRecognizer during call

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to run SpeechRecognizer while being in a call? I have done it this way:

- `BroadcastReceiver` handles change in phone state (e.g. offhook).
- the `SpeechRecognizer` is started in the current (main) thread, as it can only be started in the main thread. The application context is used for the recognizer (the current context, given to the broadcast receiver, can't start be used)

But unfortunately, the person on the other side can't hear me (the speech recognition works fine though). In away, the recognizer has "consumed" my voice and doesn't send it over.

I'm aware that doing things in the main thread during call is dangerous, but is there a way to run the recognizer somehow during call?

Update: I am trying the `TelephonyManager` listener instead of a `BroadcastReceiver`, but some internal services blow with NPEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the voice call is never handled from the Android side. Either Application processor or Communication processor has control over stream at any given time not both. Usually as soon as voice call starts the mic and headset stream control is given to Communication processor. Strangely in your case Application processor is getting control. This looks to be a bug.

The Audio stream is directly processed by the Communication processor (which makes sense since it is waste of processing to do it twice once in application processor and once in communication processor which will eventually handle the call). So i dont think this is possible.

Comment: There are apps that record your calls (you only hear your own words), so I think it should be possible somehow to both conduct the call and perform something on the speech. Probably these processors can be chained?

Comment: Can you point to apps page on google play, because i havent been able to find any

Comment: I used to have one app that records my call and even very silent version of the other participant (probably the one that can be heard from the speaker and goes into the microphone). I no longer have it (flushed my phone), and I don't remember which of the many "recording" apps it was, but I did make some recordings.

Comment: i might be wrong though, on googling some phones seem to support it. I remember doing some search long time back and the call data never seemed to go through alsa-lib.

Comment: yes, probably some phones support it. But the general idea that you have no access to the call data is a bit stupid. Fine, don't allow recording calls, but there's plenty you can do with your own words.

Comment: @Bozho: "so I think it should be possible somehow to both conduct the call and perform something on the speech" -- there is one microphone assembly. It is either owned by the call, or by the `SpeechRecognizer`. It is not owned by both. The microphone does not have a concept of a pass-through, where it both gives one app the data *and* passes the data along to some other app. Having such an ability is not an unreasonable concept, but isn't there, and for the reasons nandeesh pointed out, might not work to pass through to a phone call anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the phone model, it is possible if the speech recognizer is implemented in a service. I have no problem with the HTC Rezound with android v4, but the Motorola Bionic with android v2.3 does not work as the audio manager crashes. Even with the HTC, the recognizer could not hear the person on the other phone. With the speaker on, it keeps report error no match.