# Is it possible that voice or speech recognizer take input from speaker(incoming call voice)?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

Application Requirements :

1. During a phone call application listens to the incoming phone call i.e **incoming voice** from **speaker** not the mic.
2. **Converts** the caller's(the person who has make a call to you) **voice to text**.
3. Finally **display** that **converted text** into the **text view**.
4. It does all this conversion **while the phone call is happening**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run SpeechRecognizer during call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974218/run-speechrecognizer-during-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no.  There is no supported way for an Android application to interact with the audio stream from a phone call.  Every method that I have heard of involves playing the phone call loudly out the speaker and capturing it with the microphone, and I wouldn't even be sure that works on all devices.